# Python set remove Non Numeric values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have set value like below:

```
set(['Virtual', '120', 'P', '130', '90', '250', '100', '10', 'Mar', 'indicates', '18', '50', '40', '1', '|'])
```

How do i remove all Non Numeric value?

Output expected:

```
set(['120', '130', '90', '250', '100', '10','18',  '50', '40', '1'])
```

Comment: Have you tried anything to solve this problem? What issues did you face?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new set:

```
number_set = set()
for object in old_set:
    try: 
        number_set.add(int(object))
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")
print(number_set)
```

You can also try removing all non-numeric objects from the set:

```
for object in old_set:
    try:
        x = int(object)
    execpt ValueError:
        old_set.remove(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to clean your set:

```
s = set(['Virtual', '120', 'P', '130', '90', '250', '100', '10', 'Mar', 'indicates', '18', '50', '40', '1', '|'])

def isInt(text):
    """Returns True for a text that is convertable to int() else False."""
    try:
        _ = int(text)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

# apply filter:
filteredSet = set( filter(lambda x:isInt(x), s))

print(filteredSet)
```

Output:

```
{'18', '90', '130', '120', '40', '50', '10', '1', '100', '250'}
```

This output differs from your want's - but thats how python prints a set with print.